# WooCommerce API only returns 5 orders

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am trying to query my shop to debug why my 3rd party integration won't sync orders. I do that by sending a GET request to `https://myshop.com/wp-json/wc/v3/orders?per_page=10`. I get a total of 5 orders and these headers:

```
X-WP-Total: 5
X-WP-TotalPages: 1
```

So in other words, 5 orders total and only 1 page. If I add `&page=2` I get an empty array.

I am really unsure why this is happening and not really sure where to start debugging. I have more than 5 orders.

EDIT: When I try to edit one of the 5 orders, I see it update perfectly in the response as well. If I update a product, requesting /products also returns the new products. The orders API is messed up, somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I manged to "fix" it by turning on "High performance order storage" in WooCommerce. No clue why it stopped working and suddenly works.

[image]